# How to display and cite algorithms in an Elsevier journal (using elsarticle.cls)?

Tags: algorithms, elsarticle, pseudocode

[Elsevier's PRL guide for authors](https://www.elsevier.com/journals/pattern-recognition-letters/0167-8655/guide-for-authors) does not include any conventions to cite algorithms. However, my manuscript includes an algorithm coded using `algpseudocode` enclosed in an `algorithm` environment which numbers each algorithm in the caption.

There are some papers in IEEE that tend to display algorithms as figures. So I was thinking of replacing the `algorithm` environment with `figure` and cite it as a figure altogether but I'm not sure how this is applicable in Elsevier.

There is [one Elsevier article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031320314003835) which includes an algorithm which is simply typed as an enumerated list inline with the main text (not as a pseudocode).

Hence, how to display and cite algorithms in Elsevier? Is it alright to keep them float at the top, encapsulated as a figure, or just printed inline with the main content?

Comment: Ask at PRL, supposedly they know what they want. Personally, I would say that an algorithm is an algorithm (and not a figure), and it will be more clear to cite them as such.

Comment: @Marijn Would you rather have it inline (not as float) and without the caption heading?

Comment: That depends. Usually you need to refer to an algorithm in the text, which needs a `\label` and caption - either in a float or inline using `\captionof`. For simple cases however it may be sufficient just to write 'the following algorithm does X': and put the algorithm underneath.